# .NET MAUI: how to read an image from gallery in stream by image file name

Tags: c#, maui, image-upload

I am working on some app, where we took images with camera and store it. These images at the end of the process will be uploaded to some server. What I can't figure out how to read the image form the photo gallery as stream by name. I searched the web, but I am not sure what is the correct answer.
I need this platform specific to be done.

UPDATE:

```
private async Task UploadSurveryFiles()
    {
        var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var files = new string[1] { "IMG_20230511_201420.jpg" }; //TODO: delte

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
           //as I can tell from debug, the image was loaded 
           var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(file);
            
           //here I need the imageSource as a Straeam

            if (!imageSource.IsEmpty)
                continue;

            var isImageUploaded = await UploadFileToAWS3(file, stream);

            //TODO: update the database with the image uploaded flag
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> UploadFileToAWS3(string uploadedFileName, Stream stream)
    {
        var selfSignedUrl = await GetSelfSignedUrlForImageUpload(uploadedFileName);

        var result = await UploadFile(selfSignedUrl.UploadURL, new StreamContent(stream));

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<SelfSignedUrlForImageUploadResponse> GetSelfSignedUrlForImageUpload(string fileName)
    {
        var endpoint = $"{settings.FileUploadURL}{entity.Project.Id}/{fileName}";

        var response = await SendGetRequestAsync<SelfSignedUrlForImageUploadResponse>(endpoint);

        return response;
    }
```

My another idea is to store the images after taking them in base64 format in the App data directory.
Is that a good practice?

thnx

Comment: What do you mean by read the image form the photo gallery as a steam by name? 
Are trying to do this: Capture an image on IOS/ Android device and save it to Photo gallery then read it again from the photo gallery then upload it as a stream to the server? or what exactly you're trying to do. Please add more info

Comment: That's the flow I am attending to do.

Comment: if you are capturing the image with MediaPicker, it should return a stream you can use for uploading.  If `ImageSource.FromFile(file)` works then the image is not in the gallery, it's in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
   public async Task<Stream> ConvertImageSourceToStreamAsync(ImageSource imageSource)
{
   using var stream = await ((StreamImageSource)imageSource).Stream(CancellationToken.None);
   return stream;
}
```

Comment: I need to the the image opening form code. Sorry, for I missed that part. In the process we collect some images of house parts, and at the process end we need to upload these images to a server from code.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want exactly. The above code will allow you to open the Camera Gallery and select an image and get the Stream  or Memory Stream for that image.

Comment: I do not want to open the camera gallery. I have in my code the image file names that I need to send, because I have to more image categories that has to be send on different names.

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of your code?

Comment: U updated my question.

Comment: @Wasyster I have updated my answer. However, If you're reading the image from the gallery, there are other ways to convert it to stream

Comment: I get an invalid cast exception when trying to cast ImageSource to StreamImageSource as per your code.

Comment: @Chucky could you please post your code? or ask a new question ?